# How to get list of an account's events (labels, categories) from Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics-api

I have a request with `ga:totalEvents` and want to filter on e.g. event category. Now, I know that's available as dimension and that you can filter by using: `ga:eventCategory==myEventCategory`, but for this filter I need a list of all available event categories to choose from.

Does anyone know a way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are going to have to do it in two requests.

**First request get list of categories:**

Dimension ga:eventCategory  and metric ga:users

Save that list that is returned some place.

**Second request:**

Use that list to build your [filters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters).

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your reply!
I will try this as soon as possible. :)